# LibGDX 9patched texture drawing issue

Tags: libgdx, textures, nine-patch

So i'm making 2d pixel game and I have a trouble with 9ptach textues drawing on screen.

Code:

```
TextureRegion texture = TextureManager.navigationButton;
NinePatch patch = new NinePatch(texture, 1, 1, 1, 1);
NinePatchDrawable ninePatch = new NinePatchDrawable(patch);
background = new Image(ninePatch);
```

TextureManager.navigationButton is just atlas .9 texturregion

```
navigationButton = textureAtlas.findRegion("navigationmenu.9");
```

This is how the button looks:
[image]
[image]

I tried changing the nine patch values from like 0 to 10 or so nothing helps.

Or it looks like this (nine patch lines)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should delegate the `1, 1, 1, 1` work to [Skin](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin#overview).

```
// load the skin first
Skin skin = new Skin(...); // well, you can use even empty skin
skin.addRegions(textureAtlas);

// get the nine-patch from it
NinePatch patch = skin.getPatch("navigationmenu");
NinePatchDrawable ninePatch = new NinePatchDrawable(patch);
background = new Image(ninePatch);
```

But if you would like to use Skin, you may want to use the full power of UI using buttons, like [ImageButton](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#imagebutton). So you can define the `navigationmenu` variables in the skin itself:

```
"com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton$ImageButtonStyle":
{
    "button-navigation":
    {
        "imageUp": "navigationmenu"
    }
}
```

And then do this magic trick:

```
// add this somewhere to your scene like Image
ImageButton navigation = new ImageButton(skin, "button-navigation");
```

Comment: I used the first method and it shows 9 patch lines.

Comment: @IgnasR didn't pay attention to the images. Are black lines on the very borders of the images? Are there some pixels except alpha on borders, where black lines shouldn't be? Is the image named `navigationmenu.9.png` as it should?

Comment: The black lines are at very borders of the image, I nine patched i that way.The image was named 'navigationmenu.9.png' when I packed it became 'navigationmenu.9' _I updated the topic added an image how it is looking now_